# find the numbers that give 4 when one number is subtracted from another

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

i am supposed to find two numbers that give 4 when one number is subtracted from another. the numbers can be 1 to 6. it is supposed to print out:

```
5  1
6  2
1  5
2  6
```

i have done this but its not showing me the last two combinations. why?

```
public class number2
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        for(int i=1; i<=6; i++)
        {

            for(int j=1; j<=6; j++)
            {
                if(j-i==4)
                {
                    System.out.println(i+ " " +j);
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: One hint: `Math.abs(...)`. Either that or expand your inner if condition for **both** possibilities. You can figure this out, I'm betting. It's not really a programming problem but rather a simple math and common sense problem.

Comment: To be fair, OP looks like he's just starting out, and probably has no idea how to even use that function!

Comment: Actually one loop is quite enough.

Comment: Hint: - What is the value of `2 - 6`? It is NOT `4`!!

Comment: Further hint: what would be the result of `j - i` when j is 1 and i is 5? What result are you testing for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result like following 2 items are not printed.

5  1

6  2

It is becuase, in such situations `if(j-i==4)` is not satisfied, `j-i== -4` here instead of  `j-i==4`.

**Bearing that in mind,** if you would like to print the result as you wanted, the value for `j-i` could be `4` or `-4`.

You should include these 2 candidate situations.

Change your code with if-condition

from

```
if(j-i==4)
```

To

```
if (i - j == 4 || j - i == 4)
```

or a simple way is prefered is to use `Math.abs` method

```
if(Math.abs(j-i)==4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight change:

```
if(Math.abs(j-i) == 4){
    System.out.println(i + " " + j);
}
```